# Remove dynamic properties from QObject

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to remove all the dynamic properties assigned to a `QObject`?

Comment: Yes - just assign the invalid QVariant to them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (auto const &name : object->dynamicPropertyNames())
{
    object->setProperty(name.constData(), {});
}
Q_ASSERT(object->dynamicPropertyNames().empty());
```

This iterates over all dynamic properties and sets empty `QVariant` value.
If assertion fails than this is a Qt bug since documetation says:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dynamic-properties

> From Qt 4.2, dynamic properties can be added to and removed from QObject instances at run-time.

and

> Dynamic properties ... can be removed by setting the property value to an invalid `QVariant`.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, but it's annoying to have a huge list of empty/invalid properties.

Comment: than it is a bug, since documentation says you can remove dynamic property and there is no API accept `setProperty` to remove it.

Comment: dope, I hadn't actually read that part of the documentation. I was just assuming they didn't go away.